# Possible moves in Othello/Reversi

Tags: code-golf, board-game

[Othello/Reversi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversi) is a board game in which players take turn placing pieces of a color (dark or light) on the 8x8 board. The possible moves are positions where there are one or more pieces of the opponent's color in a straight (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal) line between that position and a piece of the player's color.

For example, on this board, the numbers on the left mark the row, the letters on the bottom mark the column, the empty spaces are marked `.`, the dark pieces are marked `D`, the light pieces are marked `L`, and the possible moves for dark are marked `*`:

```
1........
2........
3...D....
4...DD...
5.*LLLD..
6.****L..
7.....**.
8........
 abcdefgh
```

Your task is to take a board as input and output the positions of the possible moves dark can make.

## Rules

- Input and output can be in any convenient format. Possible input formats include as a string separated by newlines, as a matrix, and as a flattened list of numbers. Output positions can be in a format like `b5`, a list of two numbers, or a complex number. You may also choose to modify the input.
- The output may be in any order but cannot contain duplicates.
- You may use different values to represent `D`, `L`, and `.`, as long as they are distinct.
- You may assume that at least one move exists.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

## Test cases

```
........
........
...D....
...DD...
..LLLD..
.....L..
........
........
```

b5 b6 c6 d6 e6 f7 g7

[[1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 6]]

---

```
........
........
........
...LD...
...DL...
........
........
........
```

c4 d3 e6 f5

[[2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 5], [5, 4]]

---

```
.....L..
...LL...
.DDDD.L.
.LDDDLL.
.LLDLLL.
.L.LD...
..LLL...
.L...L..
```

a4 a5 a6 a7 b7 c1 c6 c8 d1 d8 e1 e8 f6 g6 h3 h4 h5 h6

[[0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [1, 6], [2, 0], [2, 5], [2, 7], [3, 0], [3, 7], [4, 0], [4, 7], [5, 5], [6, 5], [7, 2], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5]]

Comment: Can we output by adding the positions to the input?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, as long as the values are distinct from the input values.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>245</s> <s>238</s> <s>212</s> <s>197</s> <s>191</s> 184 bytes

```python
def f(T,*R):
 for m in range(576):
  for q in range(1,8*T[m//72][m%8]):
   w,z=m//72+m%9//3*q-q,m%8+m%9%3*q-q;d=T[w][z];b=(w>=0<=z)*(q>1<2-d)
   if-~d+b:R+=((z,w),)*b;break
 return{*R}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJNj4IwEL33VzQmhoLFz93VVfHEsSfjDYlBKS5RCkIJrhv3r7NtQYluducyb15n3jQzk3zyj5iNytKnAQzQChtLfQpgEKcwgiGDqcf2FL2O3ySr6FNDD/DEWDlRrzceuk7UnrgqCRb4YimyE7Xfe72RcTJPWDzLsK2imW@tnMJ1Lu5sa6FiYfXn1kU30GkxmA9NX5cqYWB@@53tdNmxELrgQse6sZ1tU@odAEwpz1P2ZSyv5c7LaAYt@CWLYKvVWoNubQ/AvgO7AoQQ@5ZDnpKVCa0pHGPwj@gdEPumTv7MaURfMGg0696kKrSFCQoIRdsmChDhFbh3IXUyqcqV5mCCwRVEXpKEbC/nodmaYDHUusL3hSfCm4MrkFsMWZLzDadnjiE9J3THqb@Jcy5YuV811G7IaZQhuVQeHyiTU3acuoOjKFedhILqLOKiYgSQcdOlmyXHkCNtzTTdBdDb8dw73hpa4vKqDmLzSRoyjrI4FT9CD3k6hkfKfnFP39fLHw)

A function that receives a list of strings and outputs a set containing sized-2 tuples.

- *-21* bytes by removing `i`, `j`, `a` and `b`, and replacing the `if T[i][j]=='D':` with a multiplication inside the `range`
- *-7 bytes* thank to [@Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269682/possible-moves-in-othello-reversi/269688?noredirect=1#comment585319_269688) by using two if-s instead of if-elif-else
- *-26 bytes* by removing the `f`lag variable and compacting loops `m` and `n` into one
- *-15 bytes* thank to [@Yousername](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269682/possible-moves-in-othello-reversi#comment585317_269688) (OP) by accepting a matrix of integers instead of a matrix of strings, where the empty slot is \$0\$,  a dark piece is \$1\$, and a light piece is \$-1\$
- *-6 bytes* by inlining `i` and `j` and simplifying `b`
- *-5 bytes* thank to [@Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/269682/possible-moves-in-othello-reversi/269688?noredirect=1#comment585351_269688) by inlining `n`!
- *-2 bytes* by replacing a default argument list with an `*args` tuple

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>270</s> 266 bytes

Original version.

```python
def f(T):
 R=[]
 for m in range(64):
  i=m//8;j=m%8
  if T[i][j]=='D':
   for n in range(9):
    a=n//3;b=n%3;f=0
    for q in range(1,8):
     w,z=i+q*a-q,j+q*b-q;d=T[w][z]
     if'L'==d:f=1
     elif(d=='.')*f*(w>=0<=z):R+=[(z,w)];break
     else:break
 return{*R}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJRT8IwFIXf@ytuSMw6rCDBKG5en/bYJ8LbWMxgrRahjK0ExfjbsesGCxi9Lz29@865y@7yT/O21sPDIRMSJJ34AYExxgkBuS5gBUpDkepXQe/vqkegcNXvj8IFrq5G1VXCJFZJvEgQvcirCGfUrfHR@QBS1P3@MJyhvhqGEm9ds2I3LTtgo4aGHdujut5005sNW9hzdrMJM5zEuyTeJzWipMc9xCyQOKg7Yqkkzeyr9Dy/K7t094y3T7j3g/E1xnTPdn4SzgqRvh/xUgTNvRBmW@iv7vj7ME9LUQLCl6M6nc6U9Jo6E9FJRLXgnEdHhl/ArmxWAA@M/BN6Ejw6pvM/mTb0jpE2s5nNa2Nky7aITYwi7gS3pxOnKbyBeW13mYMRI9@kWpHS@da8GPFhGIiPXMyNyF7WW2O71fLcB@spI1YlrfaXzs02XR4BtP9VG9Ar86Uy1Jtqz/cJ5IXShpbrwibSM5/PYCn0r97FeP/wAw)

- *-4 bytes* by using a set-literal instead of a set-function

---

**How does it work?**

The output variable here is `R`. Since the board is 8x8, we can iterate over it as a continuous range (`for m in range(64):`), storing the current row and column on `i` and `j`, respectively.

Every "D" piece has 8 possible directions to be validated: north, south, east, west, northwest, northeast, southwest and southeast. We also assume a "D" piece will be validated against itself: this case will be basically a no-op, and it's only considered here so that we can directly do `for n in range(9):` instead of iterating over a `range(8)` and making additional checks.

We then split `n` into two variables `a` and `b`, each containing values from 0 to 2. Basically, the following transformation is applied:

```
n = 0  -->  a = 0; b = 0  --(-1)->  a = -1; b = -1  (southwest)
n = 1  -->  a = 0; b = 1  --(-1)->  a = -1; b =  0  (south)
n = 2  -->  a = 0; b = 2  --(-1)->  a = -1; b = +1  (southeast)
n = 3  -->  a = 1; b = 0  --(-1)->  a =  0; b = -1  (west)
n = 4  -->  a = 1; b = 1  --(-1)->  a =  0; b =  0  (no-op)
n = 5  -->  a = 1; b = 2  --(-1)->  a =  0; b = +1  (east)
n = 6  -->  a = 2; b = 0  --(-1)->  a = +1; b = -1  (northwest)
n = 7  -->  a = 2; b = 1  --(-1)->  a = +1; b =  0  (north)
n = 8  -->  a = 2; b = 2  --(-1)->  a = +1; b = +1  (northeast)
```

Since a board has a limit of 8 pieces in each direction (8x8), we iterate over `range(1, 8)`. The variable `q` here describes how far we are going into the direction described by `n`: if `n` is north and `q` is 1, we are looking at the first slot on the top of `(i, j)`; if `n` is east and `q` is 2, we are looking at the second slot on the right of `(i, j)`. That slot has coordinates `(w, z)`, with value `d`.

If that slot contains a "L" piece, we can proceed with the validation; set `f`lag to true. That flag implements the requirement

> The possible moves are positions where there are one or more pieces of the opponent's color in a straight (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal) line **between that position and a piece of the player's color**.

We can only add a possible move to `R` if the `f`lag has been set; that is, if there is an "L" piece between a "D" piece and an empty slot.

If the next slot on that direction is an empty spot, a "L" piece has already been visited (i.e. if `f` is true) and if `(w, z)` is a valid spot on the board, then add it to `R` and stop validating.

Continue for all "D" pieces, for all possible directions, for all possible offsets.

Comment: You are allowed to take the input as a list of lists of integers instead, with `D`, `L`, and `.` mapping to distinct integers, which could make this a little shorter.

Comment: @Dingus thanks, so much better!

Comment: @Dingus Nice improvement! About the argument, you're definitely correct. However, I was able to reduce more two bytes by using an `*args` tuple, so it can be called consecutive times without a dummy list.

Comment: Ah, nicely done with the `*args`. I tried to do the same thing but my output always contained an empty tuple at the start that I couldn't work out how to avoid (I'm not a Pythonista).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
Ｅ⁸ＳＦ⁸Ｆ⁸«Ｊικ¿⊙Ｅ⁸⁺⪫ＫＤ⁸✳λω.D⁼⌕⁺..×⁶L…λ⌕λD¹*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU_BSgMxED13vyLkNJE04EUWPElXxRJhwd7Ew5pmbWiarJusUsQv8dKDor9U_Bkn2RYHkvfy5s0j8_GjVk2vfGN3u68httNy_1v3xkW4bTooOblx3RDvIkpPwBg7L1rfEygZOeJbMZkPm27hwXCyRsPEtAQu3PaYUNshwNwbB7XW68r0WkXjXWr9PyxjnLzioaKiiV8-D40NcGXcEnICFYJysjAbHeAMfTLbZltl9WzlO7CcZDMiTRHYPMWbjNvQE4pfe_8MjyocFv2-p9MXSx_21yKVFKJIgIikwkKpEBKJzEQiZoJa9gh5MMtxfIz9Aw) (Only using ATO here because the version of Charcoal on TIO erroneously extends the canvas when you use `PeekDirection`.) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs by drawing `*`s where the possible moves are. Explanation:

```
Ｅ⁸Ｓ
```

Copy the input to the canvas.

```
Ｆ⁸Ｆ⁸«Ｊικ
```

Jump to each square in turn.

```
¿⊙Ｅ⁸⁺⪫ＫＤ⁸✳λω.D
```

For every direction, peek in that direction, appending `.D` to the peeked string...

```
⁼⌕⁺..×⁶L…λ⌕λD¹
```

... if after truncating the string at the position of the first `D`, the result is not `.` but is a prefix of `.LLLLLL`...

```
*
```

... overwrite the `.` with a `*`.

Comment: I'm sorry but the link provided shows `L` replaced by `*`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Sorry about that, I had the wrong comparison all along and never noticed (earlier versions had extra checks in which obscured the difference).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES11), 115 bytes

Expects a matrix with \$0\$ for *empty*, \$1\$ for *light*, \$2\$ for *dark*. Returns another matrix in the same format, using \$3\$ for the possible moves for dark.

```javascript
m=>m.map((r,y)=>r.map((n,x)=>[...35678+m].some(d=>(g=X=>(q=m[Y+=~-(d/3)]?.[X+=d%3-1])&1&&g(X)|!n)(x,Y=y)*q&2)?3:n))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZBLTsMwEIb3PYWJRORpUkOJgIrK6SawssSim1ZpFlXihKDEaZ20asXjImwqBIfqJTgDzqtUCGZh_zP-5rfHbx8iC_juPaSfqyLsDfZ5Su2UpPMFxtLcArVlnQhzoxKXEGJdXl0PjNQjeZZyHFAbR3Si1iVN3alBX3s4OLPAGxF3YtDg1Or1PdD7uh7hCTyfCMAbc0q30F3qFzCybgRAc_WX5MtVLDnWwlwDIvk8uIsTPt4KH58DKbJxIWMRYSD5IokLrM3ETCgwzOTt3H_AOaI2euoglPACpYii_AdUWDlGhZRD5F6V-2WuEeZoJBYB39yH2AcAU5mUIblqQCFOYagqfibyLOEkySKsTioDWRrUX7Ruvbqau_aAPGaxwJoGrSofgQxU7cPOSzP1br8nTXSOhXMQTi0YY07LsF9wLf4oHQvmtI7sX-bYqLmE1bSjQpU6ysZxWCWY2itxsGYNzOr2esJv)

#### Commented

```javascript
m =>                         // m[] = input matrix
m.map((r, y) =>              // for each row r[] at index y in m[]:
  r.map((n, x) =>            //   for each value n at index x in r[]:
    [...35678 + m]           //     we coerce 35678 to a string and get the values
                             //     0, 1 and 2 from m[] (if the board does not
                             //     contain at least one empty, one light and one
                             //     dark square, then there's no possible move and
                             //     some() would fail anyway)
    .some(d =>               //     for each direction d:
      (g = X =>              //       g is a recursive function taking X
        ( q =                //         q is the value of the square on
          m[Y += ~-(d / 3)]  //         the updated row Y
          ?.[X += d % 3 - 1] //         and the updated column X
        ) & 1 &&             //         if it's a light one:
          g(X)               //           do a recursive call
          | !n               //           and set the final result if n != 0
      )(x, Y = y)            //       initial call to g with the current position
      * q & 2                //       test whether the last square is dark
    ) ?                      //     end of some(); if truthy:
      3                      //       set this square as a possible move
    :                        //     else:
      n                      //       leave it unchanged
  )                          //   end of inner map()
)                            // end of outer map()
```

Comment: Why `d/3%3` if `d<9`?

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks. What I initially had in mind was to use `2**29`, which requires the `%3`. Then I reverted to `"01235678"` and forgot to remove the `%3`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org) (`-p`), 60 bytes

```perl
for$i(0,7..9){s/D(.{$i}(L.{$i})+)\K\.|\.(?=(?1)D)/*/s&&redo}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kILUoZ0W0kq6BQYFS7IKlpSVpuhY3bdLyi1QyNQx0zPX0LDWri_VdNPSqVTJrNXzAlKa2Zox3jF5NjJ6Gva2GvaGmi6a-ln6xmlpRakp-LcQMqFELbt7SgwIuZIYLnOECYfj4-LjA1PigKYYwsAghM3xcYCb64FSDbBDUEh-IahcgAApxAY1xcfEBM3yANJgBN9oHqtgHqh3iRQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Google Sheets, 253 bytes

```
=let(_,lambda(a,r,regexmatch(join(,a),r)),f,"^L+D",b,"DL+$",if((H8=".")*or(_(A8:G8,b),_(I8:O8,f),_(H1:H7,b),_(H9:H15,f),_({A1,B2,C3,D4,E5,F6,G7},b),_({A15,B14,C13,D12,E11,F10,G9},b),_({I7,J6,K5,L4,M3,N2,O1},f),_({I9,J10,K11,L12,M13,N14,O15},f)),"*",H8))
```

Put the input in cells `H8:O15` and the formula in cell `X8`, and copy the formula cell to the range `X8:AE15`. The output is returned as a matrix in the latter cells, mimicking the format shown in the example in the question.

[Try it.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tgq5MPXKCjMLl1kq6fqb8PZG9fJ8my6JyxYjIzn5zHU/edit)

Generates strings by joining seven values to the left, right, up and down, and diagonally from a cell. Matches each string against a regex that looks at the start or at the end, depending on the string's direction from the origin.

[image: othello.png]

Ungolfed:

```
=let( 
  isMatch_, lambda(a, x, 
    regexmatch(join("", a), x) 
  ), 
  left, A8:G8, 
  right, I8:O8, 
  up, H1:H7, 
  down, H9:H15, 
  leftup, { A1, B2, C3, D4, E5, F6, G7 }, 
  leftdown, { A15, B14, C13, D12, E11, F10, G9 }, 
  rightup, { I7, J6, K5, L4, M3, N2, O1 }, 
  rightdown, { I9, J10, K11, L12, M13, N14, O15 }, 
  forward, "^L+D", 
  backward, "DL+$", 
  if( 
    and( 
      (H8 = "."),
      or( 
        isMatch_(left, backward), 
        isMatch_(right, forward), 
        isMatch_(up, backward), 
        isMatch_(down, forward), 
        isMatch_(leftup, backward), 
        isMatch_(leftdown, backward), 
        isMatch_(rightup, forward), 
        isMatch_(rightdown, forward) 
      ) 
    ), 
    "*", 
    H8 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒJðŒṬ⁹_ZṚ,ƊŒD;$€ẎẆ€ẎẠƇQ€ḂḄ5eðƇ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of `0`s (spaces), `1`s (dark pieces), and `2`s (light pieces) and yields a list of valid spaces at which dark may play - each as 1-indexed `[row, column]`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJK/DG45OerhzzaPGnfFRD3fO0jnWdXSSi7XKo6Y1D3f1PdzVBmMsONYeCGLvaHq4o8U09fCGY@3/H@7ekukAFAShxn0uPofbQ@MNH@5c9P@/kpJSDJceCPjo6YEYPkAayHABAqAQl54PkOEDZvgAaTADKAZWo@cDVewD0Q40CwA)** (The footer translates to the input above, calls the Link, and transforms the output to the sorted, 0-indexed `[column, row]` format used in the question's examples.)

[pretty-print version](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJK/DG45OerhzzaPGnfFRD3fO0jnWdXSSi7XKo6Y1D3f1PdzVBmMsONYeCGLvaHq4o8U09fCGY@3/H@7ekukAFAShxn0uPofbIWY1rYl3ONb1cHf3o4Y5Lj5aeo8a5h5arR/5/7@SklIMlx4I@OjpgRg@QBrIcAECoBCXng@Q4QNm@ABpMAMoBlaj5wNV7APRDjQLAA).

#### How?

```
ŒJðŒṬ⁹_ZṚ,ƊŒD;$€ẎẆ€ẎẠƇQ€ḂḄ5eðƇ - Link: Board (.:0  D:1  L:2)
ŒJ                             - multidimensional indices -> all coords
  ð                         ðƇ - keep those for which - f(coord, Board):
   ŒṬ                          -   array with a 1 at {coord} and 0s elsewhere
     ⁹_                        -   Board subtract that (i.e. Board -1 @ coord)
       ZṚ,Ɗ                    -   rotate {that} a quarter and pair with {that}
           ŒD;$€               -   concatenate each to its forward diagonals
                Ẏ              -   tighten
                 Ẇ€            -   sublists of each
                   Ẏ           -   tighten
                    ẠƇ         -   keep if: all? (those with no 0s (spaces))
                      Q€       -   deduplicate each
                        Ḃ      -   mod two
                         Ḅ     -   convert from binary
                          5e   -   five exists?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 105 bytes

```
s`\.(?=(L+|(.{7}L)+.{7}|(.{8}L)+.{8}|(.{9}L)+.{9})D|(?<=D(L+|(.{7}L)+.{7}|(.{8}L)+.{8}|(.{9}L)+.{9}).))
*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY0xDsIwDEV33wMpoVVWWomqi8e/sTKEgYGFAdhor9UD9GKpE6dRhWDAg/2@9f39uL5u90uYJ6rp5OuadkZGePqzM31nUA3GvQ8jbBVHFI2KJolWRTtaHkx/7PiPC2ct7YP16be0eZIWn7tctAUuwAoAePXgw6xAX4MKgNdE/PRsg/ITqJulZEUSw4wEkJmgRCOboecL) Link is to test suite that accepts multiple double-spaced boards. Outputs by drawing `*`s where the possible moves are. Explanation: From each `.` the regular expression tries to look both ahead or behind in each possible direction for at least one `L` followed by a `D`.

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1, 70 bytes

```
+s,T,,`.`*`([.D])(L+|(.{7}L)+.{7}|(.{8}L)+.{8}|(.{9}L)+.{9})(?!\1)[.D]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY07DsIwEER734ICycYrS6lIKpotpwsdIJmCgoYC6CDXygFyMbP@xIoQbLEzY80@3y/P6@3chGlUpHpPpNZaJNgH7Ym88xuvD45PRsO@tXttBxgbJYY2hzaFLoduMHq3OjYmXgXjE1jWNMqKZFdGLQ1Xw9kA4LmDr3I26ieoGvBMxN/OElQ@QW6zjDwpwTAjGYgmU9EoZeTzDw) Link is to test suite that accepts multiple double-spaced boards. Outputs by drawing `*`s where the possible moves are. Explanation: The regular expression matches every pair of `.` and `D` (in either order) that are separated by a run of `L`s in any of the forward directions. The `,T,,` command then transliterates the first and last character (`,,` is a step range using defaults of all three values) of each match (`,` is a regular range using defaults and is only needed so that the second range can be specified) from `.` to `*` (the `D` is therefore unaffected). The `+` then repeats until there are no more matches.